# Why is g[x] handled differently as f[x] from Mathematica?

Tags: plotting, functions, function-construction

When I execute this code:

```
\[Sigma] = 0.3;
\[Mu] = 5;
xmax = 10;
f[x_]= Exp [-(1/2) ((x - \[Mu])/\[Sigma])^2]/(\[Sigma]*Sqrt[2*\[Pi]]);
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, xmax}, PlotRange -> {0, +2}]
```

I get the plot:

[image]

But when I change f to g..

```
\[Sigma] = 0.3;
\[Mu] = 5;
xmax = 10;
g[x_]= Exp [-(1/2) ((x - \[Mu])/\[Sigma])^2]/(\[Sigma]*Sqrt[2*\[Pi]]);
Plot[g[x], {x, 0, xmax}, PlotRange -> {0, +2}]
```

I do not get anything:

[image]

Do we always have to use f as the function being plotted? Or am I missing something important here?

Comment: Works for me. I think you have a cached definition. Try `Clear[g]` and give it another go

Comment: Ohh, I didn't know that there is such a thing. I will check. Can I disable caching completely?

Comment: Nah. It's how the functions are built into the system. Basically a bunch of pattern rules. But that means you might have an extant pattern for `g` or one of the constants or something that's getting in the way.

Comment: It worked. Thanx

Comment: I always start my function definitions with `ClearAll[g]` (for func. `g`).  That's how I disable cached definitions.